# How do i pass req or res object into socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

My goal is to save an object to a req.user database. So the scenario is, whenever socket.io received something, it will save to a req.user database.

Here's the code.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('notify', function(msg){
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, found) {

      found.notifications.push(msg);
      found.save(function(err) {

        io.emit('notify', msg);
      });
    });

  });
});
```

However I received this error,

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
ReferenceError: req is not defined
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737875/getting-missing-error-handler-socket-message-using-node-js-and-socket-io

Comment: There is no solution.

Answer (score -1):

Each Socket.IO connection has a `request` property injected to it, but it's the one that made the handshake. You can use that like:

```
socket.on('notify', function(msg) {
    User.findById(socket.request...
```

But be aware of a few things:

Your user **must** be authenticated by the time the handshake happens.

If anything happens within sessions and stuff, they won't be updated, because the request is simply injected and it does not change it's state. If you are using a single page app with a single request, and sockets from there on - it should be fine, but if you are using multiple pages this is a huge risk.

Here is the thing that will work for you, but you should use it with care :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session